# How do you replace data multiple times with an array of keys using a react hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, azure-cognitive-services

I'm not sure if I worded the question right. Here is my problem. I am trying to translate my webpage dynamically using Cognitive Services Translator from Microsoft. I made a react hook with the translator. This works fine if I just need to translate one value in an object.

```
const useAzureTranslate = (data: any, lang: string, objKey: string) => {

    const [translatedData, setTranslatedData] = useState<any | null>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Promise.all(data.map(function (obj: any) {
            return axios({
                baseURL: endpoint,
                url: '/translate',
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': location,
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'X-ClientTraceId': uuidv4().toString()
                },
                params: {
                    'api-version': '3.0',
                    'from': 'en',
                    'to': lang
                },
                data: [{ "text": obj[objKey] }],
                responseType: 'json'
            }).then(response => {
                // console.log(response.data)
                let translatedText = response.data[0].translations[0].text;
                return { ...obj, [objKey]: translatedText };
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.response.data.error);
                throw error;
            });
        })).then(newDataArray => {
            // console.log(newDataArray);
            setTranslatedData(newDataArray);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
        console.log(translatedData);

        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [lang])

    return { translatedData };
}
```

I want to be able to have an array of keys instead of having to translate just one key value. I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert `objKey` to an array of strings, i.e. `objKey: string[]` and for each data element make a request for each `objKey` term? Can the endpoint take more than a single key translation at-a-time? If not this could lead to ***a lot*** of network requests, possibly even hitting a concurrent request limit. Do you have documentation on this translation endpoint you are using and what request bodies can be sent to it for processing?

Comment: Ok, found the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate#request-body). Looks like the body can take *up to* 100 elements per request. Does your code need to handle more than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"/translate"` API can take **up to** 100 terms to translate.

[Translate Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate#request-body)

> ### Request body
>
> The body of the request is a JSON array. Each array element is a JSON
> object with a string property named Text, which represents the string
> to translate.
>
> ```
> [
>     {"Text":"I would really like to drive your car around the block a few times."}
> ]
> ```
>
> The following limitations apply:
>
> - The array can have at most 100 elements.
> - The entire text included in the request cannot exceed 10,000 characters including spaces.

If your code remains within these constraints then I suggest the following:

1. Change `objKey` to be declared as an array of strings
2. Map the `objKey` array to an array of objects with `text` key
3. Merge the array of translations into a copy of the mapped `obj` object

Example:

```
const useAzureTranslate = (data: any, lang: string, objKey: string[]) => {
  const [translatedData, setTranslatedData] = useState<any | null>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(
      data.map(function (obj: any) {
        return axios({
          baseURL: endpoint,
          url: "/translate",
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey,
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region": location,
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "X-ClientTraceId": uuidv4().toString()
          },
          params: {
            "api-version": "3.0",
            from: "en",
            to: lang
          },
          data: objKey.map((key) => ({ text: obj[key] })), // <-- array of "text" objects
          responseType: "json"
        })
          .then((response) => {
            // Reduce array of translations back into current `obj` copy
            return response.data[0].translations.reduce(
              (newObj, { text }, index) => ({
                ...newObj,
                [objKey[index]]: text
              }),
              { ...obj }
            );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data.error);
            throw error;
          });
      })
    )
      .then((newDataArray) => {
        setTranslatedData(newDataArray);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      });

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [lang]);

  return { translatedData };
};
```

[image: Edit how-do-you-replace-data-multiple-times-with-an-array-of-keys-using-a-react-hook]

If your code is outside the constraints then you'll need to chunk up your data and/or key translation terms first, then make the requests as above.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. Thank you! I don't I'll need insert more than 100 elements. There is one issue I'm running into and I'm sorry that I didn't mention this before. When I need to translate multiple key values, it is within the same object. For example [{key1: text, key2: text, ...etc.}]. Otherwise, it works perfectly if I just need to translate one of the properties.

Comment: @2bootylicious I think the code above should be close to what you are after, but admittedly I don't know what the general shape of the `data` is and was only extrapolating from the existing logic. Are you saying that `{key1: text, key2: text, ...etc.}` is a single `obj` object element from `data` in the example? Could you perhaps include example `data` and `objKey` values that you want to iterate over?

Comment: So, it's kind of tricky. I receive data in 2 different ways. One is an array of objects.

[{id: '1', category: 'Inquiry/Help'}, {id: '2', category: 'Database'}, {id: '3', category: 'Hardware'}, {id: '4', category: 'Software'}, {id: '5', category: 'Network'}]

and the other is 1 object inside of an array. In this object there are multiple values I need to translate.

[{pageTitle: "Title", submitButton: "Submit", descriptionLabel:" Description", ...etc.}]

Comment: @2bootylicious I copied my solution over to a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-do-you-replace-data-multiple-times-with-an-array-of-keys-using-a-react-hook-0m1gko?file=/src/App.tsx), mocked the axios request and the code appears to function as I expected it to against your object example from your last comment. Added link to sandbox demo into answer as well.

Comment: Oh okay. I must have done something to mess it up. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @2bootylicious No worries, glad it's sufficiently working for you. Cheers.